# Apache re-direct from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, web

All,  I'm having a issues with redirecting from http to https.  My site comes up without any issue when you use either protocol.  But my redirect will never work.  I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 and Apache 2.4.25.  I have executed sudo a2enmod rewrite and have restarted apache via sudo restart apache2.

In addition, I have created an .htaccess in the root of the directory that my index.html exists.  The contents of my .htaccess file is below.  Is there anything wrong with the syntax or how I'm trying to enable redirect on my ubuntu server?  Thanks for any help!

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    # the final correct redirect
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule . https://www.abcdef.com [L,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Are you behind a load balancer? I see the X-Forwarded-Proto. If true, then consider SSL offload at the load balancer and only serve HTTP from your web site.

Comment: Thanks John!  Yes, should of mentioned, I'm behind an AWS load balancer.  I have tried looking for a solution to redirect at the load balancer level but I'm not sure how.  As of now, I have one load balancer that have two target groups.  One target group serves port 443 and the other 80.  Both target groups lead to the same ec2 server.  The ec2 server have inbound rules that accept 80 and 443.  Is there an article that I can refer to that shows the steps to perform an SSL offload and redirects to HTTP/Port 80?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of links on Amazon Load Balancers for SSL offload. Setting SSL offload is very easy plus you move all that CPU encryption / decryption to the load balancer reducing load on your EC2 instances. I highly recommend setting up SSL offloading.

[HTTPS Listeners for Your Application Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html)

[AWS Elastic Load Balancing: Support for SSL Termination](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-load-balancer-support-for-ssl-termination/)

Also take a look at Load Balancer Security Policies for SSL negotiations:

[Security Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-ssl-security-policy.html)